# Removing redo actions in NSUndoManager

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nsundomanager

I am facing an architecture question and I am wondering if anyone know if my idea is feasible or has a better architecture idea.

My situation is that I have CoreData data model for tracking some financial data, imagine it is bank accounts (it's not so don't worry about the security thing). Data for the core data objects is mainly user input.

I know well how to make user input screens (implemented as sheets on top of the main window) and how to implement undo for these input sheets. For simple sheets like edit account i simply copy data from the relevant core data object to the sheet's controller and write back on OK-Close. The write back to the CoreData object is wrapped in an undo grouping which gives me a single undoable action to restore the state to before the edit. This works fine.

Now I am contemplating a more complex edit control where the transactions on the account would be shown in an editable grid (like excel) and it would be possible to edit, add or remove actions. For this control it seem difficult to copy all data to a new data structure. Instead I was thinking of using the core data store as the data source directly, meaning core data objects would change, be created and deleted as the user edit rows in the control. Within this control i then know how to get step by step undo.

The issue comes upon end of the edit session if the user then clicks cancel. I figure to handle this instance I could wrap all actions in the control into one undo group and undo that.

The issue is that after this the canceled actions are then available as a redo on the redo stack. This is cleared as soon as the user does another undoable action but I would like to ensure that this redo action is never recorded at all.

A work around I have thought about is to do some (no-op) action that is undoable after the cancel to clear the redo stack, but then this no-op shows up in the undo stack instead which is also undesirable.

Basically what I'd like to do is to do some form of core data rollback to the state before the complex edit sheet is activated without this rollback being re-doable. The edit sheet is modal and it can be guaranteed that no other changes will happen in the core data model while the edit sheet is active.

Also worth knowing may be that the core data context is not guaranteed to be saved before the edit sheet is activated so simply throwing away the context and reloading from persistent store is not an option. (And would also lose previous undo history as well which I do not want)

The simple question is then, how do I clear the redo stack of the core data NSUndoManager? More generally does anyone know if this is the right solution to my problem or where should I look for a better design solution?

Comment: Further note to my own question. Upon writing the question the term rollback occurred to to me and further googling has revealed that in fact a disposable child managed object context may be what I am looking for. I will investigate this further.

Comment: Can't give a definitive answer here but I've tried something very similar half a year ago and decided that it's not supported by the API. I went ahead with a completely different approach instead..